# How many times has Mob reached 100%, and what emotion surfaced each time?

Tags: mob-psycho-100

When Mob reaches 100%, his esper powers explode and some emotion surfaces.

- How many times did he reach 100% (not how many times he exploded)?
- What emotion surfaced each time?
- Supply chapter / episode reference for each event if possible.

Answer (score 3):

"The emotions so far shown include:

- Anger (Chapter 8 and 90)
- Sadness (Chapter 18 and 90)
- Hostility (Chapter 32)
- Rejection (Episode 10)
- Gratitude (Chapter 47)
- Courage (Chapter 90)
- Tenacity
- Friendship
- Ecstasy (Chapter 90)
- Shame (Chapter 90)
- Compassion (Chapter 90)
- Kindness
- Resignation (Chapter 90)

Source: http://mob-psycho-100.wikia.com/wiki/Shigeo_Kageyama